# Asynchronous method doesn't work the first time

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new in Firebase. I'm using Firestore database and Ionic, I have this problem with an asynchronous call and I can't solve it. Basically in the *item* variable goes the data that I have saved in the firestore database. But when I want to show them, through a button, in a new html page a strange thing happens, in the url the passed parameter appears and disappears immediately and nothing works anymore. I had a similar problem in the past that I solved using the angular pipe "async" , but in this case it doesn't even work.
In detail, I have a list of items in a component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.itemService.getItemsList().subscribe((res)=>{
      this.Tasks = res.map((t) => {
        return {
          id: t.payload.doc.id,
          ...t.payload.doc.data() as TODO
        };
      })
    });
    
  }
```

and in item.service.ts I have defined the function:

```
constructor(
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
    private ngFirestore: AngularFirestore,
    private router: Router
) { }

  getItemsList() {
    return this.ngFirestore.collection('items').snapshotChanges();
  }
  getItem(id: string) {
        return this.ngFirestore.collection('items').doc(id).valueChanges();
      }
```

For each item I have a button to show the detail:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of Tasks" lines="full">
....
<ion-button routerLinkActive="tab-selected" [routerLink]="['/tabs/item/',item.id]" fill="outline" slot="end">View</ion-button>
```

In component itemsDescription.ts I have:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['id'];
      });
    this.itemService.getItem(this.id).subscribe((data)=>{
    this.item=data;
    });  
  }
```

Finally in html page:

```
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>{{item.id}}</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-icon name="pin" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>{{item.Scadenza.toDate() | date:'dd/MM/yy'}}</ion-label>
    <ion-card-content>{{item.Descrizione}}</ion-card-content>
```

The Scadenza and Descrizione information are shown, instead id is not. Also the url should be tabs/items/:id but when I click on the button to show the item information, the passed parameter immediately disappears and only tabs/items is displayed. If I remove the data into {{}}, the parameter from the url doesn't disappear

**SOLVED**
I followed this guide https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/async-data-to-child-page-with-ionic5/184197. So putting ? , for example {{item?.id}} now everything works correctly

Answer (score 0):

Your nested code order not right. You will get the value of id after subscription.

Check this Code:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['id'];
 this.profileService.getItem(this.id).subscribe((data)=>{
    this.item=data;
    });  
      });
   
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried with this modification but nothing changes, the parameter from the url always disappears

Comment: Check if You have received the id from the route properly using console.log(params[id]).If It's undefined so You have a problem with angular route configuration.

Comment: I receive it and it is printed correctly. I noticed that the problem is when I put the "item" data in curly brackets in the html page. If I remove it , the url works correctly. As soon as I put it back, the "id" parameter disappears from the url. It's a mystery.

Comment: Share more details about your code then We will get more chance to fix your issue. There  is no mystery in programming It the mystery itself :)

Comment: True =) . Alright, I will edit the post, thanks